# problem rendering href link in <li> using th:if condition with Thymeleaf

Tags: html, css, thymeleaf, html-lists

I have a problem with Thymeleaf: I want to show a list with a linkable sublist.
Without th:if condition no problem, but when I put It, It doesn't render the link to the controller

```
    <ul th:each="f : ${folders}">
  <li>
  <span th:text="${f.name}"></span>
    <ul th:each="s : ${f.getSub}">
        <li th:if="${s.status}">
          <span  class="disabled" th:text="${s.nome}"></span>
        </li>
        <li th:unless="${s.status}">    
        <a  th:text="${s.name}" th:ref="@{/GoToController(s_id=${s.id},d_id=${documentid} ) }"> 
        </a>
        </li>
     </ul>  
  </li>
</ul>
```

It shows me the folder and subfolder list: when the if condition is true it makes the subfolder not selectable and if it's false, it shows the linkable name of the subfolder.
Using the Chrome inspector I find out that the @Gotocontroller doesn't exist

Comment: Should this be `th:href` instead of `th:ref`?  Also you have `${s.nome}` in one and `${s.name}` in another. Which is correct?

Comment: the name is correct on eclipse. I copied another one :)